# Is it safe to use function references to register and unregister a listener?

Tags: android, kotlin

I recently found myself writing the following code:

```kotlin
fun listener() {
    // Do some stuff
    adapter.removeLoadStateListener(::listener)
}
adapter.addLoadStateListener(::listener)
```

A colleague remarked on the fact that

```kotlin
val x1 = ::listener
val x2 = ::listener
x1 == x2 //true
x1 === x2 //false
```

However,

```kotlin
var mySet = mutableSetOf<() -> Unit>()

fun a() { }

fun b() { }

mySet.add(::a)
mySet.add(::b)
mySet.remove(::a)

mySet.contains(::a) // false
mySet.contains(::b) // true
```

Based on this I get the impression I do not understand `::myFun` properly and I start to question if my original code is safe to use.

**TL;DR**

1. Is it safe to use `::listener` to reference a method to be used as a listener and that will need to be referenced multiple times (e.g. add + remove)?
2. What is actually going on behind the scenes regarding anonymous classes etc.?

**EDIT**

Eventually we decided against using `::listener` for this case. However, we ran into a new problem since `add/removeLoadStateListener` will only accept the `(CombinedLoadState) -> Unit` type.

I'll leave our solution to that problem here for future reference and other readers as it is related (I expect some may even come here looking for this rather than answers to the original question):

```kotlin
val listener = object : (CombinedLoadStates) -> Unit {
    override operator fun invoke(loadState: CombinedLoadStates) {
        // Do some stuff
        adapter.removeLoadStateListener(this)
    }
}
adapter.addLoadStateListener(listener)
```

Comment: The problem is, what you want to do? If you want to find a listener and remove that specific listener, then you can't use functions because each function invocation would be a new instance (haven't test my self, is according your own info). To solve that use an interface. If you want to remove all listeners then remove listener function just have to clear the listeners collection on the adapter. In the Android API there are both cases, classes that support only 1 listener, usually `setListner` and others that `addListener`.

Comment: > because each function invocation would be a new instance

The question is how this plays out with function references (i.e. not a function _invocation_). See my example with a set, where the `::a` entry is actually removed even though the example with variables indicate that `::a !== ::a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `::listener`, you are sort of creating an anonymous class that implements the interface, each time. However, as your test shows, the `.equals` of the anonymous classes will return that they are equal, which usually wouldn't be the case with an anonymous class (created with `object:` syntax). So, two instances created using `::listener` will be equivalent with `==` but not with `===`.

Sets typically use `.equals` equality (`==`) to determine if an instance is a duplicate, but it's possible to create a Set backed by IdentityHashMap so it effectively behaves as a Set using identity comparison. This breaks the Set contract, but a class could be using it internally for some reason.

Whether it is safe to use this depends on whether the class you're working with compares listener instances by `.equals` or identity. If it's possible it's using an IdentityHashMap to store and compare listeners, then this is not safe.

Comment: Would you mind expanding with more specifics on "sort of creating an anonymous class"?

Comment: There’s not really anything specific to say, which is why I put “sort of”. It’s wrapping the function in an anonymous class that implements the interface.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to confirm that was the case. "Sort of" made it sound like something else might be going on as well.